# Mixing GitLab CI and make - how?

Tags: gnu-make, gitlab-ci

I'm tasked with moving a `gnu-make` based build system into GitLab CI and have hit an issue - is there is a good pattern for how this should work?

The issue is that I have created a multi-stage, multi-job pipeline and carefully passed down the output from Job X to Job Y (say) as GitLab CI `artefacts` and `dependencies`.  However the `Makefile`s that I have inherited have a *fully depth of knowledge* about everything ever built so they look at the `artefacts` inherited from Job X, try to decide whether they need to be rebuilt and end up rebuilding everything that Job X built because `gnu-make` can't see the intermediate build output that Job X used inside the context of Job Y.  So basically everything is getting built many, many times and the GitLab CI `artefacts` are almost useless.

This feels like something that people must have hit before but I'm struggling to find any guidance.  Can anyone point me at some good resources that explain the best patterns for solving this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: No answers but right now I'm working around by copying the entire output into artifacts and building a bigger-and-bigger set of artifacts from each stage.  Not at all pretty :-(.

Answer (score 0):

First time replying on stack overflow - so sorry if I don't get everything as it should be...

One option that might work for you is running `make -t` before you run your make command in Job Y. Make will then create empty versions of all the missing intermediate files, and crucially set the timestamps to the same as the top-level target. This will prevent anything rebuilding. See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Avoiding-Compilation.html

One issue you can still run into is that `make -t` won't create a missing directory (underneath make is just calling `touch`). If you need to do this then I would suggest writing a rule / separate script that creates all the missing directories and files and sets their timestamps.